# How to apply newly added object in array in ng-repeat interval?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intervals

Assuming the following scenario: first click `cont!` button and then `add!`, How to apply in counting function newly pushed object in array, so that it would be displayed as last in `ng-repeat`?

Updated working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.tabs = [{
    name: "one",
    active: true
  }, {
    name: "two",
    active: false
  }, {
    name: "three",
    active: false
  }];
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.tabs.push({
      name: "display me in the counter",
      active: false
    });
  };
  $scope.count = function() {
    var i = 0;
    var interval;

    $interval.cancel(interval);
    interval = $interval(function() {

      i = i % $scope.tabs.length;
      $scope.tabs[i].active = false;
      i++
      $scope.tabs[i].active = true;
      console.log($scope.tabs.length, i)
      if (!($scope.tabs.length - 1 > i)) $interval.cancel(interval);
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    {{tabs}}
    <br>
    <button ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-default">add!</button>

    <button ng-click="count()" class="btn btn-default">count!</button>

    <div ng-repeat="no in tabs" ng-show="no.active" ng-bind="no.name">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are cashing the `$scope.tabs.length` when you invoke the `$interval` service.

If you want to display items that have been added after you call `count`, you have to check array length within you interval function, something like:

```
interval = $interval(function() {
  if ($scope.tabs.length-1 > i) {
   ...
  } else {
   $interval.cancel(interval);
  }

}, 2000);
```